# Accessing instance of class from another instance that already running

Tags: c#

I have two project in my C# visual studio solution: Main and Add. both project using different namespace. Let say: MainNameSpace and AddNameSpace.

In the Main project I have a form that had an activex windows media player component on it. I have open dialog to open the video and also a button to stop the video. this is dummy button to stop the video.

```
    public void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StopMovie();
    }

    public void StopMovie() 
    {
        axWindowsMediaPlayer1.Ctlcontrols.stop();
        MessageBox.Show("Video stoped!");  

    }
```

in my Add project I have function that want to call the StopMovie() function remotely. so I declare something like this:

```
void RemoteStop()
{
     MainNameSpace.Main ff = new MainNameSpace.Main();
     ff.StopMovie();
}
```

The code is run without error, but only execute the MessageBox ("Video Stoped!") and my video is still keep running. but when I press the stop button in the main from it does stop the video.
Am i miss something here?

Thanks.

**UPDATE: SOLVED**

I accessed via form (that already running):

```
        FormName remotekill = (FormName)Application.OpenForms["FormName"];
        if (remotekill != null)
        {
            remotekill.StopMovie();                
        }
```

Comment: Take a peek at the "Related" questions on the right-hand side; most of them are applicable to your question.

Answer (score 4):

```
MainNameSpace.Main ff = new MainNameSpace.Main();
```

This line, as it suggests, will create a **new** `Main` object (which is probably your form). So you are essentially creating a new form and try to stop the video within *that* form. This will obviously not affect the existing form that is being displayed somewhere and where the video is playing.

You will have to pass the reference of the existing `Main` somehow to your `Add` component to make this work.

Comment: sorry Im a newbie, can you elaborate more with an example regarding my case? I already read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10576856/accessing-forms-control-from-another-class-c-sharp) but seem quite different and still stuck with the messagebox popup but the video is still playing in the background.

Comment: I’m sorry, I can’t really give an example as it depends a lot on how you actually create the instances and how they are related to each other. I assume `Add` is a component within the `Main` form. If that’s the case, you could pass a reference in the constructor of `Add` or something like that.

Comment: No, AddNameSpace is another project, it hold class different from the Main Class. I just want to call the StopMovie() that exist in the main form (MainNameSpace) from the addNameSpace class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the MainNameSpace.Main instance to the class in the Add project.